# How to execute "IN" subquery only once

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have a slow SQL Server query:

```
SELECT Style
FROM Storage
WHERE Style NOT IN (SELECT ValidStyle FROM ValidStyles)
```

This syntax causes `SELECT ValidStyle FROM ValidStyles` to execute once for each row of the parent query. How can I rewrite this to run the subquery one time only?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? That should NOT run once per row, and as a rule for versions 2008 or later `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` is more efficient than a `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` check.

Comment: How are you confirming that the subquery is running once per row? Also, is ValidStyle nullable? This could contribute to unexpected results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT Style 
FROM Storage s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ValidStyles vs WHERE vs.ValidStyle=s.Style)
```

Comment: +1 This is better than "NOT IN" solutions  and left/outer joins from a performance perspective, and will do exactly what the op wants.  I wish that I could pick this as the accepted answer!

Comment: @koppinjo for almost all scenarios, `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` generate the exact same query plan and performance.

Comment: When the column you are looking at is not nullable, sure.  When that is not the case though, three weeks ago I modified a SP to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN and performance went from 40sec to 1 sec and reduced logical reads by over 80%.  These results are typical in the domain/s that I'm working in.  Query plan aside, they are not the same and as a general rule I think it is safe to default to NOT EXISTS.  Just my opinion though.

Comment: This is still running the subquery for each row

Answer (score 0):

I'm just take a guess here, but this should work....

```
 SELECT S.Style 
 FROM Storage S 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidStyles vs on S.Style = VS.ValidStyle
 WHERE vs.ValidStyle is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Style
FROM Storage S
LEFT JOIN ValidStyles VS
ON
 S.Style = VS.ValidStyle
WHERE VS.ValidStyle IS NULL
```